# Git and SSH, which key is used?

Tags: git, ssh

Say your `.ssh` directory contains 30 keys (15 private and 15 public).

Where in Git can one check which one is used to connect to a given remote repository?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The following entry in `.ssh/config` file solves the problem

```
  host git.assembla.com
  user git
  identityfile ~/.ssh/whatever
```

Where `~/.ssh/whatever` is a path to your private key

Additionally, user and host can be picked up from

```
git push git@git.assembla.com:repo_name.git
         ^__ ^_______________
         user host
```

Comment: so if I wanted to use another ssh key for a different host, would I just repeat the same after the first?? Does the identityfile pertain to the first host before it?

Comment: ok, yea, it seems like that's the case https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/force-ssh-client-to-use-given-private-key-identity-file/

Answer (score 109):

Executing ssh in verbose mode, aka `ssh -v user@host`, will print a huge load of debugging info, which also contains details on which keyfiles it is trying for login.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 332
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

Now if you combine this, with the Step 4 in Git's own [SSH help page](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#step-4-test-everything-out), `ssh -vT git@github.com` can give you the answer.

Note: You can also use the `-i` switch to tell ssh during command execution, which keyfile to use.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845799/show-ssh-key-file-in-git-bash

Comment: You can also grep the standard error output of the ssh command to find the key file like this: `ssh -vv user@host 2> >(grep Offering)` - this will make things easier. The last file should be the public key. For example: `debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/macbookpro/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: `github` is not the same thing as `git`.

Answer (score 53):

I'd say most practical to my taste would be:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v' git …
```

of course, depending on circumstances it might be beneficial just to export it to current SHELL's environment so that you won't have to prepend it manually each time. Then it'd be this way:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'
git …
```

— As `man git` suggests there're a few of environmental variables that would affect Git's operations with use of SSH. According to `man ssh` you can get some debugging info when deploying `-v` option (not only but also, check out the manual if you're curious for more).

> which key is used?

In the output you would see smth like …

```
debug1: Offering public key: …
```

… which is the answer to your question.

Comment: YES. This should be the accepted answer. To make it work on windows CMD (ugh), use: `set GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -v`.

This helped me figure out that the ssh-config Inlcude-Path should be something like this on windows: `Include /C/Users/YourUserName.ssh/config` to make ssh and thus git use a config file which then uses for example a `HOST *` entry to specify the identity file git/ssh uses.

Comment: @icyerasor your command did not work for me as it thinks that `-v` belongs to `set`. This worked for me `$env:GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'`.

Answer (score 24):

Unless it is specified on the `.ssh/config` it will use the default private key file.

The default file is `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `~/.ssh/id_dsa` or `~/.ssh/identity` depending on the protocol version.

Comment: When the keys are added to known hosts ?

Answer (score 19):

This might be super edge, but after running `ssh -vT git@github.com` it showed me it was checking `/root/.ssh` for the keys, I was expecting it to check my home directory and then I realized I was logged in as root!

Comment: This technique, among other the same `ssh` way of interrogation are the correct solutions. Thanks.

Comment: This was the most useful answer, it really shows you what ssh key is used. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 8):

Since `git` just uses `ssh` to connect, it will use whichever key `ssh` would use to connect to the remote host. See the `~/.ssh/config` file for details; the `host` block uses the `IdentityFile` directive to specify the private key to use. The `ssh_config(5)` manpage contains full details.

Comment: Hmm .. the file does not exist on my system. Should it?

Comment: @JAM What OS are you using? Also, sometimes the config file is at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Comment: I am on MACOS. Found `/etc/ssh_config` which appears to be a file full of commented entries

Comment: @sarnold You could create `~/.ssh/config` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

On the remote server, edit the sshd_config file and change LogLevel from INFO to VERBOSE and restart ssh.

Now your log file will hold the fingerprint of the key that was used to authenticate each user.

On Ubuntu, these files are:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
/var/log/auth.log
```

but they may be different on another distro. Just google for their location (some use /var/log/secure for example).