# Show SSH key file in Git Bash

Tags: git

How can I see which SSH key file is used in Git Bash?

I tried "git config --get-all", but I get the error message

> error: wrong number of arguments; usage: git config [options]

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Which SSH key is used isn't determined by Git, but by the SSH client itself. Either the appropriate key is configured in `~/.ssh/config`, or `ssh` just tries all keys it can find when connecting to the host. You can see which key ultimately succeeded by connecting to the host with the standard SSH client. For example, when using GitHub:

```
ssh -v git@github.com
```

This will give you something a bit like this:

```
[...]
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa2
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen ****
[...]
```

This tells you that the key `.../id_rsa2` was the one accepted by the server.

Comment: How does this work on Windows where there is no default command line ssh client to run?

Comment: @HansHarhoff In Windows 10, PowerShell includes the OpenSSH Client. Just make sure this optional feature is activated (Search for "Manage optional features" in Windows).

Comment: Git for Windows normally includes its own SSH client, which should be available from Git Bash.

Answer (score 76):

Another solution, in the latest Git Bash, you can type:

```
$ git-gui
```

Then a GUI application is executing, and in the GUI, you can just click *Help* → *Show SSH Key* to show your SSH key.

Answer (score 17):

This command worked for me:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: This only works if you are using the default RSA key at the default location. If your key has another name or you are using other types (like ED25519), this doesn't work.

Comment: Also it does not work on Windows by default